# Documenting auto-generated code

Tags: c#, documentation, code-generation

I use code-generation for my data access layer and Doxygen for documentation. My problem is that I can't add Xml comments on the generated classes since they will be overwritten as soon as I re-generate the code. To be more precise I can add Xml comments to my custom methods (which are in a separate file as partial classes) but I can't do it on data properties.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What code generating tool are you using?

Comment: CodeSmith, although I believe this applies to almost any code-generation tool (except if I am missing a super-cool feature :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Doxygen, [you don't have to write your documentation scattered throughout the file](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#structuralcommands), so you can keep it separate from the generated code and prepend it to the generated file as a post-generation step.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the documentation in your model, and have your CST templates pull out & write that information to the generated code.

For example, you can comment (is comment the right word? Maybe the field is called summary) tables and columns in your SQL database - i know of a few codegen solutions that automatically put that text into your code...